# Argo CD argocd-autopilot error ComparisonError rpc error: Manifest generation error (cached): bootstrap\argo-cd: app path does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, argocd, autopilot

I am following argocd-autopilot [Getting Started](https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-autopilot/blob/main/docs/Getting-Started.md) guide on windows 10 using powershell.

I am creating these env variable:

$env:GIT_TOKEN = ghp_oOaezyetwer345345

$env:GIT_REPO = https://github.com/myorg/argocdinfra

I made sure my kubernetes context is minikube and run Bootstrap Argo-CD command:

**argocd-autopilot repo bootstrap**

After executing this command I could see the repo $env:GIT_REPO being created with folders:

- apps
- bootstrap
- projects

After clonning $env:GIT_REPO, here is the content of argo-cd\kustomization.yaml that, I think is supposed to manage argo-cd itself.

After loging in to ArgoCD GUI I can see 3 apps, but Argo-CD app in in Uknown status and there is one error:
ComparisonError
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Manifest generation error (cached): bootstrap\argo-cd: app path does not exist

Content of: C:\argocdinfra\bootstrap\argo-cd\kustomization.yaml

```html
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
configMapGenerator:
- behavior: merge
  literals:
  - |
    repository.credentials=- passwordSecret:
        key: git_token
        name: autopilot-secret
      url: https://github.com/
      usernameSecret:
        key: git_username
        name: autopilot-secret
  name: argocd-cm
kind: Kustomization
namespace: argocd
resources:
- github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-autopilot/manifests/base?ref=v0.2.28
```

**I don't quit understand this customization and if I need to do anything else in either my git repo or argocd GUI after initial setup.**

**What I tried was set
repository.credentials
url = https://github.com/myorg/argocdinfra
but I still get the same error.**

**Is this related to the fact that I use a private github org?
Note autopilot-bootstrap and root applications are OK**

[[image: ArgoCD argo-cd application error2]

Answer (score 1):

i have responded to your [issue](https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-autopilot/issues/454) in argocd-autopilot issues page. i *think* you might be running an outdated version to the binary. the original problem was with the `argo-cd.yaml` file tries to reference `bootstrap\argo-cd`, while it should be `bootstrap/argo-cd` - this issue was resolved in v0.4.11

please let us know if you are running an updated version and still encounter the same issue, so we will find the root cause and fix it.

Comment: You are right. Indeed I used Choco installation on windows and the latest version there is much older than the current latest binary. Can you update documentation so others need to be aware and download the tool directly